# how to update SVN on a folder and build a csproj automatically?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, tortoisesvn

i'm extending my precompiling application by automating the following steps:

1) update the SVN on a folder (we're using TortoiseSVN, unfortunately)

2) do a programmatic build on the csproj after an update was made

I would like to know how i can accomplish these in c#?

thanks.

Comment: Is this for development workstations or a build server? How limited are you in modifying the software installed on the machine? It sounds like what you really want is a batch file that calls out to the command-line SVN tools, not to hook into Tortoise directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should also consider using CruiseControl.NET to manage all your continuous integration tasks.

Comment: instead of re-creating the wheel, i'll just learn CruiseControl. Thanks Johann!

Answer (score 0):

Use reflector to take a look at the custom msbuild task for svn update, and compile, and see how it's already been done for you.

Or write a process.exec method  in c# that call's the command line for svn update, and msbuild compile .

Comment: hi, can you give me a link on this? i appreciate it.